# Having issue running JAVA program inside BASH script

Tags: java, bash

I have a bash script that look like below. All I am doing here is trying to run a java program passing in classpath and other inputs.

```
[guest@server1]# cat runJava
#!/bin/bash
JARS=/home/guest/lib/*
CONFIG=/home/guest/AnalyticServer.properties

echo JARS=$JARS
echo CONFIG=$CONFIG
echo "java -cp \"$JARS\" com.test.ASDataSourceClient DELETE -c \"$CONFIG\" -n test_ds"
java -cp "$JARS" com.test.ASDataSourceClient DELETE -c "$CONFIG" -n test_ds
```

The java program runs perfectly fine when run directly on command line/terminal. I even tested running all the commands from above script on terminal directly(one by one) and verified that java program runs fine. However, when I launch these commands via script, I am having issue. It doesn't even seem to execute echo "java -cp .." command properly.

Could anyone advice what I may be missing.

```
[guest@server1]# bash runJava
JARS=/home/guest/lib/*
CONFIG=/home/guest/AnalyticServer.properties
" -n test_dsaSourceClient DELETE -c "/home/guest/AnalyticServer.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/ASDataSourceClient
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.ASDataSourceClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.test.ASDataSourceClient.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: Your echo is fine and should be showing. The error message is from java. How are you running the scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way globbing works, `JARS=/home/guest/lib/*` won't do what you want.

Instead, you can use either

```sh
JARS=(/home/guest/lib/*)  # Put all the jars in an array 
IFS=:                     # Set the field separator to :
java -cp "${JARS[*]}" ... # Join all the array elements on the field separator
```

or less obscurely

```sh
JARS=""
for jar in /home/guest/lib/* # Loop through all the jar files
do
    JARS="$JARS:$jar"        # Append the jar file to the variable
done 
java -cp "$JARS" ...
```

This will make the `JARS` variable contain a colon separated list of jar files.

Comment: You can also do string contatenation with: `JARS+=":$jar"` -- not sure what version of bash that requires. Also, trim the leading colon with `"${JARS#:}"`

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to point to the directory containing JARs. You need to name them explicitly, e.g.

```
JARS="/home/guest/lib/spring-beans-3.0.5.jar:anotherlibrary.jar"
```

Comment: Thanks, I would try that method but don't understand why * wouldn't get expanded to look for all the jar files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I notice this odd line in your script output:

```
" -n test_dsaSourceClient DELETE -c "/home/guest/AnalyticServer.properties
```

That indicates $CONFIG ends with a `\r` character. Are you editing this script in a Windows text editor? Remove carriage returns in your script with `dos2unix`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

JARS=/home/guest/lib
CONFIG=/home/guest/AnalyticServer.properties

echo JARS=$JARS
echo CONFIG=$CONFIG

for file in `ls $JARS/*.jar`;
do
    classpath=$classpath:$file
done

cmd="java -classpath $classpath com.test.ASDataSourceClient DELETE -c $CONFIG -n test_ds"
echo $cmd
exec $cmd
```

Comment: There are two problems with this answer: iterating over the output of `ls`, and relying on the word-split expansion of a parameter to be equivalent to the original command line. Both will break when they involve file names that contain whitespace.